# PSTricks raises an error while using RightAngleType=german

Tags: pstricks, miktex

I moved some files from one computer to another. The first computer was able to compile all the files without errors. The second computer is not able to compile these files as soon as a I change the `RightAngleType` from default or suisseromand to german. The `default` and `suisseromand` option works well, but the `german` one raises an error.

```
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(9,9)
  \psset{unit=2cm,linewidth=1.5pt, PointSymbol=none}
  \pstTriangle[DrawCirABC=true,PosAngleC=90](0.9,1){A}(2.9,1){B}(1.8,2){C}
  \pstRightAngle[linewidth=1pt,RightAngleType=german]{A}{C}{B}
\end{pspicture}
```

I use MikTex 2.9 and I compile the file from Latex -> PS -> PDF.

The Error Log looks like:

```
! Argument of \undef has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.37 ...ewidth=1pt,RightAngleType=german]{A}{C}{B}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \undef was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.37 ...ewidth=1pt,RightAngleType=german]{A}{C}{B}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

In my configuration file I load the following packages:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through,backgrounds, intersections,shapes.geometric,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-bar, pst-plot}
```

Maybe there are problems using this packages together?
I hope somebody has an idea how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

no problem with current TeXLive 2011:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(9,9)
  \psset{unit=2cm,linewidth=1.5pt, PointSymbol=none}
  \pstTriangle[DrawCirABC=true,PosAngleC=90](0.9,1){A}(2.9,1){B}(1.8,2){C}
  \pstRightAngle[linewidth=1pt,RightAngleType=german]{A}{C}{B}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}

 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pst-eucl.sty    2011/08/04 package wrapper for PSTricks pst-eucl.tex
pstricks.sty    2011/10/31 v0.52 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2011/09/04 v2.23 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2011/09/04 v2.23 `PST-fp' (hv)
pstricks.pro    2011/10/31 v. 1.08, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-algparser.pro    2011/10/31 v. 0.04, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-tools.pro    2011/04/23 v. 0.01, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-dots.pro    2006/12/19 v. 2.00, PostScript prologue file (hv)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
pst-eucl.tex    2011/11/20 v1.42 `PST-eucl' (dr)
pst-eucl.pro    2011/08/04 v. 1.00, PostScript prologue file (hv)
 ***********
```

And looking at your preamble I'll ask myself "why do I write documentations??"

Comment: Fine, now I know I did something wrong in my preamble. To which of the 100 documentations on the pstricks page are you refering to?